# SwiftUI - Two navigation bars

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem, after I register a new user, the app goes back to the main menu (using a NavigationLink), then if I choose one of the options in the menu, in the next view I have 2 navigation bars.

Im working with NavigationView in the MainView.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

}

```
struct MainView: View {
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: AuthView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Sesion")
                })
            
        }
        
}
```

}

```
struct AuthView: View {

@State private var email: String = ""
@State private var password: String = ""

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)

var body: some View {
        VStack() {
          
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: RegisterView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Registrarse")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 60)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .cornerRadius(15.0)
                    })
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle("Autenticacion")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

}

```
struct RegisterView: View {
@ObservedObject var registerController = RegisterController()

@State private var showingRegistrationAlert = false

@State var navigateNext = false

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
            Spacer()
            
            NavigationLink(destination:  ContentView(), isActive:$navigateNext) {
                                Text("")
            }
                Button(action: { if registerController.validateRegistration() {
                    showingRegistrationAlert.toggle()
                }}) {
                    Text("Enviar registro")
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showingRegistrationAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Se registro correctamente"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok"), action: {
                        navigateNext.toggle()
                    }))
                
            }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Registracion"), displayMode: .inline)
    
}
```

}

I tried to put the less code possible, sorry if it's a lot.

Comment: this is very common issue, and 1000 time answered!  have you searched in older questions?

Comment: Yes, but I can't solve it, ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding second NavigationView in RegisterView. That is the issue! because of using ContentView, for solving use MainView().

```
 struct RegisterView: View {
@ObservedObject var registerController = RegisterController()

@State private var showingRegistrationAlert = false

@State var navigateNext = false

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
            Spacer()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: MainView(), isActive:$navigateNext) {             // <<: here
                                Text("")
            }
                Button(action: { if registerController.validateRegistration() {
                    showingRegistrationAlert.toggle()
                }}) {
                    Text("Enviar registro")
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showingRegistrationAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Se registro correctamente"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok"), action: {
                        navigateNext.toggle()
                    }))
                
            }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Registracion"), displayMode: .inline)
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only want to have NavigationView be on the TOP view in your hierarchy - don't use it on any of the child views, even if presented by a NavigationLink.

Edit: If you're already doing this, please post a code sample and I can look in more detail.

Another option I favour is wrapping SwiftUI views in a UIHostingController and using UIKit for navigation - since NavigationLinks have been buggy since release.

Comment: Yes, im already doing that, now im gonna post the sample, ty.