# NavigationBackButton and space between List-headline and NavigationBackButton

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationlink

How can i prevent that:
[image]
and that:
[image]
I mean the space between the navigationbackbutton and the List and the Sports back button. The regions back button can stay.
The code looks like this:
home.swift:

```
struct Home: View {
var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination:example1(),
                    label: {
                        Text("to example1")
                    }
                )
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("home"))
        }}
```

example1.swift:

```
struct example1: View {
var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination:example2(),
                    label: {
                        Text("to example2")
                    }
                )
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("example1"))
        }}
```

example2.swift:

```
struct example2: View {
var body: some View {

        Text("hello world")
        }
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code.

Comment: there is only a navigationview and link. no other modifiers.

Comment: @Konsti_x08 You do need to show a [mre] otherwise we can't debug the problem. However, it looks like you have nested `NavigationView`s if I had to guess.

Comment: @George i added some code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Two navigation bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424548/swiftui-two-navigation-bars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have nested `NavigationView`s. You only want one, at the top level of whatever you need navigating.

All you need to do is remove the `NavigationView` in `example1`, like so:

```
struct example1: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: example2(),
                label: {
                    Text("to example2")
                }
            )
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("example1"))
    }
}
```